# В чем разница между словами "выгодней" и "выгоднее"?

Tags: морфология

То и другое, согласно словарям, - прилагательные, сравнительная степень к "выгодный". Но разница-то между ними есть. Или "выгодней" - более просторечный вариант?

Answer (score 2):

> Простая форма сравнительной степени имен прилагательных образуется синтетически — прибавлением к основе положительной степени продуктивного суффикса -ее (в разговорной речи и в стихотворном языке -ей) 
>   http://www.gumer.info/bibliotek_Buks/Linguist/DicTermin/s_5.php
>
> Суффикс -ее, его вариант – суффикс -ей – носит разговорный оттенок
>   http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200700709

Answer (score 2):

В словарях при "выгодней" можно найти пометку "разг." (пример: П. Червинский, Наречие. Дидактический словарь, с. 58). Смыслового различия нет, но меньшее количество слогов в некоторых случаях удобно, напр. для поддержания ритма стихотворной строки.